# For loop in Tcl programming langage

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to execute a silly 'for' loop in `tcl` :

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
      puts $i
}
```

but I get this error :

```
line 1: syntax error near unexpected token 'i'
line 1: 'for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {'
```

Comment: it seems theres nothing wrong with your [tcl syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/for.htm), if you save the file as test.tcl and execute `tclsh test.tcl`. Could it be that you use a wrong intepreter, like bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your script is not being evaluated by Tcl, as that is definitely not an error message that Tcl generates (unless you write code to do so explicitly, i.e., not in this case!) It looks like it might be being evaluated by bash.

Try running your script like this (with the right filename, of course):

```
tclsh yourscript.tcl
```

If that works, change the start of your script to read:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
```

After that, just code normally as before.

---

There are other initial incantations that are somewhat popular:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
```

```
#!/bin/sh
# some comment with a backslash at the end of the line \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}
```

But these are not as good as using `/usr/bin/env` which is simple, reliable and portable.